# Incorrect UNIX timestamp from String Date

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a date in String format into UNIX timestamp, I am able to convert it but when I check the timestamp it displays incorrect date.

I am using the following code to convert a Date in String to Unix timestamp:

```
String selected_date = "16/11/2015 1:34 am";
        datetime.setText(selected_date);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy hh:mm a");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = dateFormat.parse(selected_date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        long unixTime = (long)date.getTime()/1000;
```

The output UNIX timestamp is: `1460309640`

But when I convert that timestamp using a web tool it returns: `4/11/2016, 1:34:00 AM`

Answer (score 4):

The format

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy hh:mm a");
```

is not compatible with the string

```
String selected_date = "16/11/2015 1:34 am";
```

16 can't be a month!

2015 is not a year in two digits format

The right format seems to be (not sure if kk or KK depending on hours if 0 based or not)

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm a");
```

Comment: In fact, it appears to be wrapping the date around. The output is 4/11/2016, which could be construed as the "16th month of 2015".

Comment: How do I make 2015 to 15?

Comment: yyyy for 2015, yy for 15